# Adding items to list of ReferenceField in mongoengine

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

I have the following structure of my collection in mongo.

```
class SkillCluster(DynamicDocument):
    Name = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    SubClusters = ListField(StringField())
    ModifiedDate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['ClusterName'],
        'index_background': True,
        'collection': 'SkillClusters',
        'db_alias': db_alias_name
    }


class Skill(DynamicDocument):
    Name = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    Clusters = ListField(ReferenceField(SkillCluster))
    ModifiedDate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    meta = {
        'indexes': ['SkillName'],
        'index_background': True,
        'collection': 'Skill',
        'db_alias': db_alias_name
    }
```

A sample document of SkillCluster collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad089263b3f4f5d68d74d7f"),
    "Name" : "Sciences",
    "ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-04-13T10:40:38.152Z"),
    "SubClusters" : [
        "Biology",
        "Biotech",
        "Chemistry",
        "General"
    ]
}
```

A skill may belong to different clusters to I have a `Clusters` list field in my `Skill` collection. I have come up with following code to add a skill

```
def add_skills(skill_name, cluster_string):
    cluster_sub_clusters = cluster_string.split(':', 1)
    cluster_name, sub_cluster_name = cluster_sub_clusters[0], cluster_sub_clusters[-1].strip()
    # query to test if the "SkillCluster" collection has a document that has both the cluster_name in "Name" fields & sub_cluster_name in "SubClusters" array 
    result_set = SkillCluster.objects(Name=cluster_name, SubClusters__contains=sub_cluster_name)
    if result_set:
        data_dict = {
            "ModifiedDate": datetime.utcnow(),
            "Clusters": {
                "$addToSet": result_set[0]
            }

        }
        skill = Skill.objects(Name=skill_name).modify(upsert=True, new=True, **data_dict)
    else:
        # check if document exists with name = cluster_name, if so then add sub_cluster_name to the "SubClusters" array
        result_set = SkillCluster.objects(Name=cluster_name)
        if result_set:
            result_set[0].update(add_to_set__SubClusters=sub_cluster_name)
            # ........... rest of the logic
```

But I am getting this error -

```
File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py", line 277, in update
    value = field.prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 708, in prepare_query_value
    return [self.field.prepare_query_value(op, v) for v in value]
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 708, in <listcomp>
    return [self.field.prepare_query_value(op, v) for v in value]
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 997, in prepare_query_value
    super(ReferenceField, self).prepare_query_value(op, value)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 174, in prepare_query_value
    self.validate(value)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 1003, in validate
    self.error('A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents')
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 149, in error
    raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name)
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents
```

How should I add reference objects to ListField.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the modify function is causing the problem.

MongoEngine uses Django-style update keyword arguments for both `update()` and `modify()` functions. So maybe you should try something like this:

```
data_dict = { 
    #"ModifiedDate": datetime.utcnow(),
    add_to_set__Clusters : result_set[0] # <= Django-style update/modify keyword arguments
} 
skill = Skill.objects(Name=skill_name).modify(upsert=True, new=True, **data_dict)
```

Here is the link to MongoEngine API Reference: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html search for `update()` and `modify()` and also refer to atomic-updates section for a list of possible update keywords: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates